# How to trigger a jenkins build with the new pull requested branch from bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, integration

I am trying to initiate a Jenkins build which is triggered on pull request creation and update in the bitbucket. I want to do the jenkins build with the new requested branch( the PR branch) rather than the master.
If I am integrating on the webhook, the jenkins build is triggered , but it triggers the build on master rather than the requested branch.

Can someone let me know the integration can be done from bitbucket so that I can submit a build with the new incoming branch?

Comment: There's a dedicated plugin you can use for the case described https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder. Try it, it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on how your Jenkins build is defined.  If you look in the BitBucket documentation, you'll find that there are environment variables in the scope of the webhook that you can reference in the URL that you send to Jenkins.  One of those variables is the branch name. If your Jenkins job is a pipeline job, you can define a parameter to the job representing your branch name, and you can use that variable in the pipeline script to check out the specified branch.